# time complexity: google.common.base.Joiner vs String concatenation

Tags: java, time-complexity, guava, complexity-theory

I know that using += on strings in loops takes O(n^2) time where n is the number of loops. But if the loop will run at most 20 times. Will that change the time complexity to O(1) ? For example,

```
List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
//some operations to add string to strList
for(String str : strList) appendStr += str + ",";
```

I know that the size of strList will never exceed 20. Also each string in strList will have less than 20 characters.
If the string concatenation in this case still has O(n^2) time complexity, would it better be to use `google.common.base.Joiner` if I want my algorithm to have a better time complexity?

Comment: += with string in a loop is bad.

Comment: If an algorithm is O(N^2), it's O(N^2), whatever the value of N is. Use a StringBuilder.

Comment: if the loop will run at most 20 times. Will that change the time complexity to O(1) ? yes. Big O notation is about *asymptotic* time complexity meaning you should only compare two algorithms using this notation when the size of inputs gets arbitrarily large.

Comment: This takes O(N) time, why do you think it's `n^2`? Also, it's a bad way to write `String appendStr = strList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch If `n` is the number of strings added to the result, then `string += string` in a loop is _O(n^2)_ because the first string will be *copied* `2 * n` times, second string is copied `2 * (n-1)` times, ..., resulting in _O(n^2)_ complexity. Remember, this is worst case, e.g. no JIT optimization.

Comment: Don't even think about using a more verbose, less readable and slower solution. Go for `Joiner` or `Collectors.joining`; writing needless loops may be a good exercise, but we know already, you can do it. Btw., your limit of 20 may one day become 20000 or do you think, requirement never change?

Comment: @Andreas it is not clear what N we are talking about. If the list size is fixed and N is the maximum string length in the list, then time complexity is O(N). For a list size of M, time complexity is O(N*M), and if as the OP implies, both list size and max string size are constant, then the time complexity of the code is O(1).

Comment: @jrook OP doesn't say that list size and max string size are constant, just that they are limited to 20, each. If input had been constant, then there would be no `n`, making question immaterial. Since `n` is usually a *count* of inputs, it can be either list size (the usual `n`), or the total number of characters in the input (less likely `n`). Since list size is the most obvious `n`, my previous comment stands: The time complexity, based on number of times an input value is *copied*, is _O(n^2)_ when using `string += string`, assuming JIT doesn't optimize that away.

Comment: @maaartinus that's interesting, but according to actual tests on java-9, this seems to be the other way around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a very pedantic sense yes, if your input is capped at a fixed size than any operations performed on that input are effectively constant-time, however that misses the purpose of such analysis. Examine how your code behaves in the [*asymptotic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity) case if you are interested in its time complexity, not how it behaves for a single specific input.

Even if you cap the size of the list to 20 elements, you're still doing O(n^2) "work" in order to concatenate the elements. Contrast that with using a `StringBuilder` or higher-level tool such as `Joiner` which are *designed* to be more efficient than repeated concatenations. `Joiner` only has to do O(n) "work" in order to construct the string you need.

Put simply, there's *never* a reason to do:

```
 for(String str : strList) appendStr += str + ",";
```

instead of:

```
Joiner.on(',').join(strList);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Eugene, it's always good to have hard data to look at. Prior to Java 9 your benchmark would look very different (I believe). Even with Java 9 I'd be very wary of using `+=` in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

I have completely erased my previous answer, because the tests that I had were seriously flawed. Here are some updated results and code:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 2, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class DifferentConcats {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder().include(DifferentConcats.class.getSimpleName())
                                          .verbosity(VerboseMode.EXTRA)
                                          .build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Param(value = {"1", "10", "100", "1000", "10000"})
    private int howMany;

    private static final Joiner JOINER = Joiner.on(",");

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(3)
    public String guavaJoiner() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(howMany);

        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
            list.add("" + i);
        }
        return JOINER.join(list);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(3)
    public String java9Default() {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(howMany);

        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; ++i) {
            list.add("" + i);
        }

        String result = "";

        for (String s : list) {
            result += s;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark                      (howMany)  Mode  Cnt         Score         Error  Units
DifferentConcats.guavaJoiner           1  avgt   15        62.582 ±       0.756  ns/op
DifferentConcats.java9Default          1  avgt   15        47.209 ±       0.708  ns/op

DifferentConcats.guavaJoiner          10  avgt   15       430.310 ±       4.690  ns/op
DifferentConcats.java9Default         10  avgt   15       377.203 ±       4.071  ns/op

DifferentConcats.guavaJoiner         100  avgt   15      4115.152 ±      38.505  ns/op
DifferentConcats.java9Default        100  avgt   15      4659.620 ±     182.488  ns/op

DifferentConcats.guavaJoiner        1000  avgt   15     43917.367 ±     360.601  ns/op
DifferentConcats.java9Default       1000  avgt   15    362959.115 ±    6604.020  ns/op

DifferentConcats.guavaJoiner       10000  avgt   15    435289.491 ±    5391.097  ns/op
DifferentConcats.java9Default      10000  avgt   15  47132980.336 ± 1152934.498  ns/op
```

**TL;DR**

The other, accepted answer, is absolutely correct.

Comment: That's a cool benchmark to see, it looks like Java 9 has introduced some optimizations around successive string concatenations. That said, fundamentally `for (...) x += ...;` is an O(n^2) operation, so I'd be wary of relying on this optimization in practice. Also, the comparison with `Joiner` isn't really fair since it's doing more work (inserting `,` in-between each entry) than the other methods.

Comment: @dimo414 you are right about the extra ","- update the tests (the result does not change). But I don't get your first argument, how come can we *not* rely on it? it was specifically done so that we *could rely* on it

Comment: The `+=` operator has to do O(n) work (copy both strings into a new string). Therefore a `+=` call in a loop has to do O(n^2) work. Compiler optimizations may be able to transform *some* such loops into a more efficient implementation that only does one copy at the end, but there's no way to be sure, short of inspecting the JIT-generated bytecode at runtime, that a particular loop will benefit from the optimization.

Comment: Put another way, your benchmark demonstrates that `+=` in a loop *may* be fast, but it doesn't demonstrate that it *will* be fast. By contrast using `StringBuilder` or `Joiner` is documented to be linear-time.

Comment: The guava joiner benchmark constructs a new `Joiner` instance every time. What are the performance implications of reusing the instance instead? Also, this test uses far fewer iterations than I'd expect. Normally thousands, tens of thousands, or more, at used for java microbenchmarks.

Comment: @MattBall you need to get an understanding what `JMH` is (this is exactly what it does: runs tens of thousands of tests, yes). I have also re-factored this answer entirely.

Comment: @dimo414 you were right all along - and I have changed and refactored my answer. 3 years after I can conclude that I was an idiot at the time of writing this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to state that the Guava's `Joiner` would work more effectively with 100% assurance due to JVM runtime optimizations, under certain circumstances a plain concatenation would work faster.

That's said, prefer `Joiner` (or similar constructs that utilizes a `StringBuilder` under the hood) for concatenating collections since it's readability and performance, in general, are better.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great blog post explaining the performance of each Concatenation technique in details [java-string-concatenation-which-way-is-best](https://redfin.engineering/java-string-concatenation-which-way-is-best-8f590a7d22a8)

Note : Concatenation performance varies with no. of strings to concatenate. For example - to concatenate 1-10 strings, these techniques works best - StringBuilder, StringBuffer and Plus Operator. And to concatenate 100s of strings - Guava Joiner, apache's stringsUtils library also works great.

Please go through the above blog. It really explains performance of various concatenation Techniques very well.

Thanks.